# How does this lambda for sorting numbers work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, lambda

```
#code for sorting big integers
lis = ['234', '5', '2', '12435645758']

lis.sort(key = lambda x: len(x))
print lis
#output ['5', '2', '234', '12435645758']

lis.sort(key = lambda x: (len(x), x))
print lis
#output ['2', '5', '234', '12435645758']
```

Am trying to sort big number strings in Python without converting the strings to integers and couldn't understand how these lambda expression are evaluated.

The first lambda expression is sorting based on length of string and sorting the list, but what does the second one do? I would like to know how the second lambda expression is evaluated.

Comment: This is not a bad question.. Why the -2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda returns a tuple for each value in the list. Those tuples are then used to inform the sort order. So instead of comparing `'234'` with `'5'`, the sort algorithm is asked to compare `(3, '234')` and `(1, '5')`.

Python sorts tuples [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), that is to say, by comparing the first elements of two tuples first, then if those are the same, moving on to compare the second elements, etc. until there are no elements left to compare.

Because the tuple holds both the length and the string itself, for strings of equal length the strings are next sorted on their actual value. This puts longer strings at the end, shorter strings at the front, and *within each group of equal length*, the strings are sorted by their value.

Looking at your input example again, for `'234'` and `'5'`, the resulting tuples `(3, '234')` and `(1, '5')` have unequal first elements so `(1, '5')` is sorted before `(3, '234')`. But for `'5'` and `'2'`, the resulting tuples are `(1, '5')` and `(1, '2')` (both are 1 character long), and the first elements of these tuples are equal. So they are sorted on the second element instead, putting `'2'` before `'5'`.

Without such tie breakers (so the keys being equal), Python leaves the relative order intact. For your first example, the sort key is merely `len(x)`, and since `'5'` and `'2'` have the same length and there is nothing else to compare them by, Python puts them into the output in the same relative order, `'5'` before `'2'`.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples, Lists and Strings compare their ["Lexicographical order (Wikipedia link)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). That means they compare the elements for **equality** beginning from the left. As soon as one element is not equal they compare if that element is smaller or bigger.

In your second `sort` you create a tuple containing the **length** and then the **string**. So if you compare two elements it will check: If the length is unequal the shorter one will be considered "smaller". If the length is equal the number with the lower "string representation" is "smaller".

That's roughly equivalent to sorting by length first and then by the string representation:

```
lis = ['234', '5', '2', '12435645758']

class StringInteger(object):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.string = string

    def __lt__(self, other):   
        """ that's the method that implements "smaller than": < comparisons."""
        # check if the lengths are equal
        if len(self.string) == len(other.string):
            # lengths are equal, so compare the strings
            return self.string < other.string
        else:
            # lengths are not equal, compare the lengths
            return len(self.string) < len(other.string)

sorted(lis, key=StringInteger)  # ['2', '5', '234', '12435645758']
```